# MongoDB Property String Starts With Query And Set Group Id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Data structure - **one document** in a big collection:

```
{
  OPERATINGSYSTEM: "Android 6.0"
}
```

Issue: The operatingsystem can equal e.g. "Android 5.0", "Android 6.0", "Windows Phone", "Windows Phone 8.1"

There is  no property which only contains the kind of operating system e.g. only `Android`.

---

I need to get the count of windows phones, and android phones.

My temporary solution:

```
db.getCollection('RB').find(
    {OPERATINGSYSTEM: {$regex: "^Android"}}
).count();
```

I'm doing that query replacing `"^Android"` by windows phone and so on which takes much time and needs to be done in parallel.

Using the aggregation framework I though about this:

```
db.RB.aggregate(
{$group: {_id: {OPERATINGSYSTEM:"$OPERATINGSYSTEM"}}},)
```

But using this I  get an entry for each operatingsystem version `Android 5.0`, `Android 6.0` etc...

The solution I'm searching for should return data in this format:

```
{
  "Android": 50,
  "Windows Phone": 100
}
```

How can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map reduce, and apply your logic in the map function.

```
var map  = function(){
    var name = this.op.includes("android") ? "Android" : ""; // could be a regexp

    if(name === ""){
        name = this.op.includes("windows") ? "Windows" : "";
    }

    emit(name, 1);
}

var reduce = function(key, values){
    return Array.sum(values)
}

db.operating.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "total"})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/

Comment: You're right the aggrigation framework is not the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Provided your strings at least consistently have the numeric version as the last thing in the string, then you could use [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) with the aggregation framework to make an array from the "space delimited" content, then remove the last element from the array before reconstructing:

Given data like :

```
{ "name" : "Android 6.0" }
{ "name" : "Android 7.0" }
{ "name" : "Windows Phone 10"  }
```

You can try:

```
db.getCollection('phones').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": { "split": { "$split": [ "$name", " " ] } },
        "in": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": { "$slice": [ "$$split", 0, { "$subtract": [ { "$size": "$$split" }, 1 ] } ] },
            "initialValue": "",
            "in": {
              "$cond": {
                "if": { "$eq": [ "$$value", "" ] },
                "then": "$$this",
                "else": { "$concat": [ "$$value", " ", "$$this" ] }   
              }
            }
          }
        } 
      }
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": [[{ "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" }]]
    }  
  }}
])
```

That's all possible if your MongoDB is at least MongoDB 3.4 to support both `$split` and `$reduce`. The `$replaceRoot` is really about naming the keys, and not really required.

Alternately you can use `mapReduce`:

```
db.getCollection('phones').mapReduce(
  function() {
    var re = /\d+/g;
    emit(this.name.substr(0,this.name.search(re)-1),1);
  },
  function(key,values) { return Array.sum(values) },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } } 
)
```

Where it's easier to break down the string by the index where a numeric value occurs. In either case, you are not required to "hardcode" anything, and the values of the keys are completely dependent on the strings in context.

Keep in mind though that unless there is an extremely large number of possible values, then running parallel `.count()` operations "should" be the fastest to process since returning cursor counts is a lot faster than actually counting the aggregated entries.